# Violin tuner using python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyaudio

I am trying yo write a python script to act as a violin tuner / real time spectral display. So far I got pyaudio to record blocks of data from the microphone and can compute the frequency spectrum for short times series of audio. I would like to plot those in real time using matplotlib, but my figure window is blank while the data is been recorded and only the last plot is updated on the screen, after the script ends. What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May  1 00:03:55 2017

@author: Hugo.
"""

import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep


CHUNK = 2**14 #2**15 #4096
WIDTH = 2
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
dt = 1.0/RATE


### frequencies of the strings for the violin (tunned in A), in Hz
f4 = 195.998   ## G3
f3 = 293.665   ## D4
f2 = 440.000   ## A4
f1 = 659.255   ## E5

n = CHUNK
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d = dt)

def Frequency_of_position(position):
    """ Returns the frequency (Hz) of the note in from its position (halftones)
    relative to A4 in an equal tempered scale. Ex: 0 -> 440 Hz (A4), 
    12 -> 880 Hz (A5)."""
    return 440.0*(2**(1.0/12.0))**position


def Position_to_note(position):
    "A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#"
    SCALE = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"]
    LETTER = SCALE[position % 12]
    NUMBER = str(int((position+48) / 12))
    return LETTER+NUMBER

pos = np.array(range(-36,48))
vnote_freqs = np.vectorize(Frequency_of_position)
note_freqs = vnote_freqs(pos)


def get_frequency( spectrum ):
    return freqs[np.argmax(spectrum)]



class Freq_analysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()
        self.plots = self.prepare_figure()
        #self.fig_and_axes = self.prepare_figure()
        #self.first_plot = self.plot_first_figure()


    def stop(self):
        self.stream.close()

    def open_mic_stream( self ):
        device_index = self.find_input_device()

        stream = self.pa.open(   format = FORMAT,
                                 channels = CHANNELS,
                                 rate = RATE,
                                 input = True,
                                 input_device_index = device_index,
                                 frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

        return stream

    def find_input_device(self):
        device_index = None            
        for i in range( self.pa.get_device_count() ):     
            devinfo = self.pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)   
            print( "Device %d: %s"%(i,devinfo["name"]) )

            for keyword in ["mic","input"]:
                if keyword in devinfo["name"].lower():
                    print( "Found an input: device %d - %s"%    (i,devinfo["name"]) )
                    device_index = i
                    return device_index

        if device_index == None:
            print( "No preferred input found; using default input device." )

        return device_index

    def prepare_figure(self):
        fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize = (16,6))
        wide_plot = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
        plt.vlines([f1,f2,f3,f4],1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("S^2 (u. arb.)")
        plt.xscale('log')
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([80,4000])
        #plt.xlim([600,700])
        #plt.xlim([400,500])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_w, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f4_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,5)
        plt.vlines(f4,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("S^2 (u. arb.)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([140,260])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f4, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f3_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,6)
        plt.vlines(f3,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([220,380])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f3, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f2_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,7)
        plt.vlines(f2,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([400,500])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f2, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f1_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,8)
        plt.vlines(f1,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([600,700])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f1, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        plt.show()

    #return fig1, wide_plot, f1_plot, f2_plot, f3_plot, f4_plot
        return spec_w, spec_f1, spec_f2, spec_f3, spec_f4


    def PrintFreq(self, S2):
        dominant = get_frequency( S2 )
        dist = np.abs(note_freqs-dominant)
        closest_pos = pos[np.argmin(dist)]
        closest_note = Position_to_note(closest_pos)
        print(dominant, "(",closest_note, "=",Frequency_of_position(closest_pos),")")

    def listen(self):
        try:
            block = self.stream.read(CHUNK)
        except IOError:
            # An error occurred. 
            print( "Error recording.")
            return
        indata = np.array(struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(block)/2),block))
        n = indata.size
        freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d = dt)
        data_rfft = np.fft.rfft(indata)
        S2 = np.abs(data_rfft)**2
        #self.PrintFreq(block)
        #self.update_fig(block)
        self.PrintFreq(S2)
        self.update_fig(freqs, S2)

    def update_fig(self, freqs, S2):
        self.plots[0].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[1].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[2].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[3].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[4].set_xdata(freqs)

        self.plots[0].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[1].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[2].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[3].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[4].set_ydata(S2)

    #plt.draw()
    #plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tuner = Freq_analysis()

    for i in range(1000):
        Tuner.listen()
        plt.show()
```

Comment: For a simple example using `matplotlib.animation` see my example application [plot_input.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/plot_input.py). It doesn't transform the signal into the frequency domain, but I think this could be added easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot run the code I can only guess. But it seems you never actually redraw the canvas.

Try adding

```
self.plots[0].figure.canvas.draw_idle()
```

at the end of the `update_fig` function.

This might or might not work. So you might also want to try interactive mode. Turn `plt.ion()` and add

```
plt.draw()
plt.pause(0.0001)
```

at the end of the `update_fig` function. At the end you might turn `plt.ioff()` and call `plt.show()` to keep the figure open.

The following code runs fine for me:

```
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep


CHUNK = 2**14 #2**15 #4096
WIDTH = 2
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
dt = 1.0/RATE


### frequencies of the strings for the violin (tunned in A), in Hz
f4 = 195.998   ## G3
f3 = 293.665   ## D4
f2 = 440.000   ## A4
f1 = 659.255   ## E5

n = CHUNK
freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d = dt)

def Frequency_of_position(position):
    """ Returns the frequency (Hz) of the note in from its position (halftones)
    relative to A4 in an equal tempered scale. Ex: 0 -> 440 Hz (A4), 
    12 -> 880 Hz (A5)."""
    return 440.0*(2**(1.0/12.0))**position


def Position_to_note(position):
    "A A# B C C# D D# E F F# G G#"
    SCALE = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"]
    LETTER = SCALE[position % 12]
    NUMBER = str(int((position+57) / 12))
    return LETTER+NUMBER

pos = np.array(range(-36,48))
vnote_freqs = np.vectorize(Frequency_of_position)
note_freqs = vnote_freqs(pos)


def get_frequency( spectrum ):
    return freqs[np.argmax(spectrum)]



class Freq_analysis(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.open_mic_stream()
        self.plots = self.prepare_figure()
        #self.fig_and_axes = self.prepare_figure()
        #self.first_plot = self.plot_first_figure()


    def stop(self):
        self.stream.close()

    def open_mic_stream( self ):
        device_index = self.find_input_device()

        stream = self.pa.open(   format = FORMAT,
                                 channels = CHANNELS,
                                 rate = RATE,
                                 input = True,
                                 input_device_index = device_index,
                                 frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

        return stream

    def find_input_device(self):
        device_index = None            
        for i in range( self.pa.get_device_count() ):     
            devinfo = self.pa.get_device_info_by_index(i)   
            print( "Device %d: %s"%(i,devinfo["name"]) )

            for keyword in ["mic","input"]:
                if keyword in devinfo["name"].lower():
                    print( "Found an input: device %d - %s"%    (i,devinfo["name"]) )
                    device_index = i
                    return device_index

        if device_index == None:
            print( "No preferred input found; using default input device." )

        return device_index

    def prepare_figure(self):
        plt.ion()
        fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize = (16,6))
        wide_plot = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
        plt.vlines([f1,f2,f3,f4],1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("S^2 (u. arb.)")
        plt.xscale('log')
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([80,4000])
        #plt.xlim([600,700])
        #plt.xlim([400,500])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_w, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f4_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,5)
        plt.vlines(f4,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.ylabel("S^2 (u. arb.)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([140,260])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f4, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f3_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,6)
        plt.vlines(f3,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([220,380])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f3, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f2_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,7)
        plt.vlines(f2,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([400,500])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f2, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        f1_plot = plt.subplot(2,4,8)
        plt.vlines(f1,1,1e17, linestyles = 'dashed')
        plt.xlabel("freq (Hz)")
        plt.yscale('log')
        plt.xlim([600,700])
        plt.ylim([1e0,1e17])
        spec_f1, = plt.plot([1,1],[1,1], '-',c = 'blue')

        plt.draw()

    #return fig1, wide_plot, f1_plot, f2_plot, f3_plot, f4_plot
        return spec_w, spec_f1, spec_f2, spec_f3, spec_f4


    def PrintFreq(self, S2):
        dominant = get_frequency( S2 )
        dist = np.abs(note_freqs-dominant)
        closest_pos = pos[np.argmin(dist)]
        closest_note = Position_to_note(closest_pos)
        print(dominant, "(",closest_note, "=",Frequency_of_position(closest_pos),")")

    def listen(self):
        try:
            block = self.stream.read(CHUNK)
        except IOError:
            # An error occurred. 
            print( "Error recording.")
            return
        indata = np.array(struct.unpack("%dh"%(len(block)/2),block))
        n = indata.size
        freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(n, d = dt)
        data_rfft = np.fft.rfft(indata)
        S2 = np.abs(data_rfft)**2
        #self.PrintFreq(block)
        #self.update_fig(block)
        self.PrintFreq(S2)
        self.update_fig(freqs, S2)

    def update_fig(self, freqs, S2):
        self.plots[0].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[1].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[2].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[3].set_xdata(freqs)
        self.plots[4].set_xdata(freqs)

        self.plots[0].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[1].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[2].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[3].set_ydata(S2)
        self.plots[4].set_ydata(S2)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Tuner = Freq_analysis()

    for i in range(100):
        Tuner.listen()
    plt.ioff()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: I edited the code so now you can run it. Adding `...canvas.draw_idle()` didn't work either. I also tried `plt.draw()` and  `plt.show()`, with `plt.ion()` and `plt.ioff()`. That's what is puzzling me.

Comment: For me it works. I added the code that I can run fine on my computer.

Comment: Yes, it did work in my computer, too. I found that I was using `sleep()` instead of `plt.pause()`. Using `plt.pause()` did the trick. Thanks! Now this raises another question: what is the difference between `plt.pause` and `sleep`?

Comment: time.sleep literally lets the application sleep, i.e. nothing happens and the window becomes unresponsive. plt.pause starts the event loop of the plot window such that all events can be processed and stops it after a certain time, such that the rest of the script can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add some sleep time between plot updates. You probably indended so, since you have imported the `sleep`.

```
from time import sleep

...

for i in range(1000):
    sleep(10)
    Tuner.listen()
    plt.show()
```

However, a better practice would be using the `matplotlib.animation` module, check out the [official example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/unchained.html)!

Comment: I tried with sleep. It doesn't work. Apparently the `pyaudio` operation is taking precedence over the figure update. The figure remains blank until the end of the script, no matter how much time I put in the sleep. Thanks for the tip about `matplotlib.animation`. I'll try it next, but I'm afraid the same problem will happen.